# how to handle API unified return format in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have some probem when decode api data to dart model, below is the api response

{
        "code": 200,
        "message": "操作成功",
        "data": [
            { "id": 4, "locationId": 1, "coverImg": "cfe4bf63-2752-497c-bb02-60c57ef3f22f.png", "redirectType": 1, "redirectValue": "12", "sort": 12, "isDeleted": 0, "createTime": null, "updateTime": "2020-05-12 11:14:25" },
            { "id": 5, "locationId": 1, "coverImg": "d3bf3347-36ce-40ab-bc5b-78a779a3d58e.png", "redirectType": 1, "redirectValue": "10", "sort": 12, "isDeleted": 0, "createTime": null, "updateTime": "2020-05-12 11:14:48" },
            { "id": 16, "locationId": 1, "coverImg": "0a1aeb3f-8850-42e5-b7df-307eca058fed.png", "redirectType": 1, "redirectValue": "15", "sort": 5, "isDeleted": 0, "createTime": "2020-05-13 15:00:39", "updateTime": "2020-05-13 15:00:39" }
        ]
    }

i want conver this json string to Model below

```
class CommonResult<T> {
  final int code;
  final T data;
  final String message;

  CommonResult(this.code, this.data, this.message);

  CommonResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : code =json['code'],
    data = json['data'],
    message =json['message'];
}

class Banner {
  final String coverImg;
  final int id;
  final int isDelete;
  final int locationId;
  final int sort;
  final String redirectValue;
  final int redirectType;

  Banner(this.coverImg, this.id, this.isDelete, this.locationId,
      this.sort, this.redirectValue, this.redirectType);

  Banner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : id =json['id'],
    coverImg = json['coverImg'],
    isDelete = json['isDelete'],
    locationId = json['locationId'],
    sort = json['sort'],
    redirectValue = json['redirectValue'],
    redirectType = json['redirectType'];
}
```

convert code

```
    Future<List<Banner>> getHttp() async {
        Response response;
        Dio dio = new Dio();
        response = await dio.get("url");
        print(response);
        var bannerResult = CommonResult<List<Banner>>.fromJson(response.data);
        return bannerResult.data;
  }

      @override
      void initState() {
        getHttp().then((value) {
          print(value);
        });
      }
```

then result in console throw Exception  Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'

```
flutter: {"code":200,"message":"操作成功","data":[{"id":4,"locationId":1,"coverImg":"cfe4bf63-2752-497c-bb02-60c57ef3f22f.png","redirectType":1,"redirectValue":"12","sort":12,"isDeleted":0,"createTime":null,"updateTime":"2020-05-12 11:14:25"},{"id":5,"locationId":1,"coverImg":"d3bf3347-36ce-40ab-bc5b-78a779a3d58e.png","redirectType":1,"redirectValue":"10","sort":12,"isDeleted":0,"createTime":null,"updateTime":"2020-05-12 11:14:48"},{"id":16,"locationId":1,"coverImg":"0a1aeb3f-8850-42e5-b7df-307eca058fed.png","redirectType":1,"redirectValue":"15","sort":5,"isDeleted":0,"createTime":"2020-05-13 15:00:39","updateTime":"2020-05-13 15:00:39"},{"id":18,"locationId":1,"coverImg":"bf59eda5-2baa-4f70-9581-642eaf533e7b.png","redirectType":2,"redirectValue":"https://c1111.com/","sort":0,"isDeleted":0,"createTime":"2020-05-13 15:03:3<…>
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Banner>'
#0      new CommonResult.fromJson (package:recruit_app/models/commonResult.dart:15:10)
#1      _HomePageState.getHttp (package:recruit_app/pages/HomePage.dart:81:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _HomePageState.initState (package:recruit_app/pages/HomePage.dart:88:5)
#3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4640:58)
#4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved by code below thanks for @tesla1984's answer

```
class BannerEntity {
  final String coverImg;
  final int id;
  final int isDelete;
  final int locationId;
  final int sort;
  final String redirectValue;
  final int redirectType;

  BannerEntity(
      {this.coverImg,
      this.id,
      this.isDelete,
      this.locationId,
      this.sort,
      this.redirectValue,
      this.redirectType});

  BannerEntity fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return BannerEntity(
        coverImg: json['coverImg'],
        id: json['id'],
        isDelete: json['isDelete'],
        locationId: json['locationId'],
        sort: json['sort'],
        redirectValue: json['redirectValue'],
        redirectType: json['redirectType']);
  }
}
```

for List result

```
class CommonListResult<T> {
  int code;
  String message;
  List<T> data;

  CommonListResult({this.code, this.message, this.data});

  factory CommonListResult.fromJson(
      Map<String, dynamic> json, Function fromJson) {
    final items = json['data'].cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    List<T> mData =
        new List<T>.from(items.map((itemsJson) => fromJson(itemsJson)));
    return CommonListResult(
        code: json['code'], message: json['message'], data: mData);
  }
}
```

for Base result

```
/// @author  hayden zhou
/// @date  2020/5/31 11:12 下午

class CommonResult<T> {
  final int code;
  final T data;
  final String message;

  CommonResult(this.code, this.data, this.message);

  CommonResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, Function fromJson)
      : code = json['code'],
        data = fromJson(json['data']),
        message = json['message'];
}
```

and for pageList

```
class CommonPageResult<T> {
  int code;
  String message;
  PageResult<T> data;

  CommonPageResult({this.code, this.message, this.data});

  factory CommonPageResult.fromJson(
      Map<String, dynamic> json, Function fromJson) {
    return CommonPageResult(
        code: json['code'],
        message: json['message'],
        data: PageResult<T>.fromJson(json['data'], fromJson));
  }
}

class PageResult<T> {
  List<T> list;
  int pageNum;
  int pageSize;
  int total;
  int totalPage;

  PageResult(
      {this.list, this.pageNum, this.pageSize, this.total, this.totalPage});

  PageResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, Function fromJson) {
    if (json['list'] != null) {
      list = new List();
      json['list'].forEach((v) {
        list.add(fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    pageNum = json['pageNum'];
    pageSize = json['pageSize'];
    total = json['total'];
    totalPage = json['totalPage'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you sperate the `Object data` and the `List data`

```
class BaseEntity<T> {
  int code;
  String message;
  T data;

  BaseEntity({this.code, this.message, this.data});

  factory BaseEntity.fromJson(json) {
    var data;
    if (json[RESPONSE_DATA] != null)
      data = JsonConvert.fromJsonAsT<T>(json[RESPONSE_DATA]);

    return BaseEntity(
        code: json[RESPONSE_CODE],
        message: json[RESPONSE_MESSAGE],
        data: data);
  }
}

class BaseListEntity<T> {
  int code;
  String message;
  List<T> data;

  BaseListEntity({this.code, this.message, this.data});

  factory BaseListEntity.fromJson(json) {
    List<T> mData = List();
    if (json[RESPONSE_DATA] != null) {
      (json[RESPONSE_DATA] as List).forEach((v) {
        mData.add(JsonConvert.fromJsonAsT<T>(v));
      });
    }
    return BaseListEntity(
        code: json[RESPONSE_CODE],
        message: json[RESPONSE_MESSAGE],
        data: mData);
  }
}
```